# Proof of Fréchet Differentiability - general instruction and specific problem

Tags: real-analysis, frechet-derivative

I'd like to know if anyone could provide a general instruction to proving that a function is Fréchet differentiable. I've run into some problems where usually I can propose a form for the linear operator $D_{f,x}$, but I'm having trouble with that.

The specific case I refer in the title is:

Let $\phi: \mathbb{C}[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by:

$$\phi(f) = \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|^2 \ dt.$$

Prove that it is Fréchet differentiable and compute $D_{\phi,f}$.

I've tried solving this and reached the following result:

---

$$D_{\phi,f} = 2\int_{0}^{1} g(z)f(z) \ dz$$

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tell us more ... how did you "reach" that result?

Comment: I have calculated it beginning with this: (assuming $g \in \mathbb{C}[0,1]$)

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (1/t) (\phi(f+gt) - \phi(f))$.

By the tone of your answer it sounds like I'm wrong.

Comment: @juanarroyo I believe he means continuous functions on $[0,1]$ or $C[0,1]$ rather than a complex domain.

Comment: That is right, it's the Continuous functions on [0,1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Frechet derivative generalizes the notion of derivative to functionals. As with functions, there are some well known cases with a formula, but in general, we have to go back to the definition. The Frechet derivative of a functional $K$ at $f$ is a linear functional $L_f$ for which 
$K(f+g) = K(f) + L_f(g) +R(g)$ and
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{\|g\|\rightarrow 0}
\frac{\|R(g)\|}{\|g\|}
=
0
\end{equation*}

In your case, 
\begin{equation*}
K(f)
=
\int_0^1
f(t)^2
dt
\end{equation*} 
and
\begin{align*}
K(f+g)
&=
\int_0^1
(f(t)+g(t))^2
dt\\
&=
\int_0^1
f(t)^2
dt
+
2\int_0^1
f(t)g(t)
dt
+
\int_0^1
g(t)^2
dt
\end{align*}

So, we define $L_f$ and $R$ to be the latter two terms. Then we can verify that $|R(g)|\rightarrow 0$ faster than $\|g\|\rightarrow 0$. Hence $L_f$ is in fact the Frechet derivative.

**Note**
To clarify a few of the comments below, the norm on $R$ is just absolute value and the norm on $g$ is the $L^{\infty}$ norm. So we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\|R(g)\|}{\|g\|}
&=
\frac{|\int_0^1 g(t)^2 dt   |}{\| g\|_{\infty}}\\
&\leq
\frac{\int_0^1 \|g\|_{\infty}^2 dt  }{\| g\|_{\infty}}\\
&=
\| g\|_{\infty}
\end{align*} 
which converges to zero as $\| g\|_{\infty}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thank you, Dunham. I''ll check the last steps and answer back again. So the answer in the question was actually right?

Comment: yes, you were correct. But it is important to verify that it is in fact the derivative by showing the relationship in my answer and showing that the remainder term goes to 0 sufficiently fast.

Comment: As I choose $L_f = 2\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t)dt$, then $R(g)$ = $\int_{0}^{1}g(t)^{2}dt$ and I get $\lim_||g||\rightarrow0$ $|R(g)|/(||g||)$. Since this space is infinite, norms aren't equivalent; and my problem set doesn't provide a norm for functions. I could answer using the norm $||g||_1$ = $\int_{0}^{1}g(t)dt$; but how should I divide this integrals? Also, I could use $ ||g||_\infty = sup{|g(t)|: t \in [0,1]} $, arguing that if the sup is tending to zero, then for every t in [0,1], the function is also tending to zero (and faster since sup is the an upper bound). Is that right?

Comment: Without it being specified, I would assume the infinity norm. The integral approaches 0 faster since g is squared.

Comment: The second part of your answer would be in relation to the norm 1, right? For the infinity norm, since for every point the function is lower than it's sup, it's converging to zero faster than the sup; is that argumentation right?

Comment: b) I've also tried, instead of $(f + g), (f + gt)$, and passing the limit as $t$ tends to zero. It seemed easier since in the final calculations I was left with $t$ times the integral of $g(t)^2$, so as t tended to zero, so did this term. Is that correct? 

P.S. I'm not sure if forum rules allow this, but I've also posted another question about this. I'd like to know if I was right on the norm I choose. If you wouldn't mind... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663915/proof-verification-help-on-last-step-fr%C3%A9chet-differentiable-of-bilinear-func?noredirect=1#comment5502469_2663915

Comment: With the infinity norm it's pretty straightforward. I've added details above. Adding the t, you lose generality, and that's really not the proper approach.